Difference in differences event study to support parallel trends
I did an analysis using a Difference-in-Differences setup with a staggered treatment design and conducted an event study to verify the parallel trends assumption. The attached figure for one of the dependent variables shows non-significant effects in lagged periods, despite a significantly positive overall treatment coefficient indicating a substantial ATT. I believe this discrepancy may arise because the aggregated ATT reflects a cumulative beneficial effect across all post-intervention periods, while individual period effects might not each be strong enough to achieve statistical significance due to variability or insufficient power. However, I am not sure I am right about this and would appreciate some further guidance.

I'm just curious, which period serves as your reference period? Is it the period immediately before the intervention?

@ThomasBilach Thanks for the hint. I used the intervention period itself. There seems to be a consensus towards using the period right before the intervention though, so I adjusted this, and excluded the lead 1 indicator in the model to avoid multicollinearity issues. I added the new event study plot to the post. The coefficients do shift up. However, I still have the same issue with the coefficients not being significant, while the ATT seems to be.

May I ask why you initially omitted one of the post-treatment periods?

@ThomasBilach I don' think I did that. I didn't exclude any of the periods, which is an issue, so I corrected that.
